# Recursion in conditional definition in Haskell gives error ( Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:)

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, tuples, type-mismatch

I want to define a function conditional and using recursion in Haskell (ghci 7.x) like:

```
partitions n k m = gfunct n k m
       where
       gfunct n k m
         | n == 0 && k == 0 = 1
         | n < m  || k == 0 = 0
         | otherwise        = gfunct (n-m,k-1,m+1) + gfunct (n,k,m+1)
```

I get an error:

```
fib.hs:20:35:
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
  a1 ~ t6 -> (t5, t6, t7) -> a1
Relevant bindings include
  m :: (t5, t6, t7) (bound at fib.hs:17:23)
  k :: t6 (bound at fib.hs:17:21)
  n :: (t5, t6, t7) (bound at fib.hs:17:19)
  gfunct :: (t5, t6, t7) -> t6 -> (t5, t6, t7) -> a1
    (bound at fib.hs:17:12)
In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely
  ‘gfunct (n - m, k - 1, m + 1)’
In the expression:
  gfunct (n - m, k - 1, m + 1) + gfunct (n, k, m + 1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To improve these error messages, it is common practice to write explicit type annotations for top-level functions. Indeed, it is usually recommended to start writing a function starting from its type, and use the type as a guide to write the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function

```
g a b c = 0
```

will return `0` if supplied by three values, `a`, `b` and `c`; but a function

```
g (a,b,c) = 0
```

will return `0` if supplied by *one* value `(a,b,c)`. Which is a *triple* of values, `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: So the solution is "otherwise        = gfunct  (n-m) (k-1) (m+1)  + gfunct (n) (k) (m+1)". Thank you very much!!